# Tensorflow, how to remove padding (specific values) from tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using the dataset API to batch data from a tfrecords file. The data has varying length rows. Since in order to use the `batch()` function all the rows need to be equal size, I need to use `padded_batch()` instead. This paddes all the rows within a batch to match the size of the biggest row in the batch.

After the batching, is there a way to remove these padded values?

Here is a minimal example where I use '-1' as the padded values

```
import math
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

import math
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

#Set up data
cells = np.array([[0,1,2,3], [2,3,4], [3,6,5,4,3], [3,9]])
mells = np.array([[0], [2], [3], [9]])
print(cells)

#Write data to tfrecords
writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter('test.tfrecords')
for index in range(mells.shape[0]):
    example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
        'num_value':tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=mells[index])),
        'list_value':tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=cells[index]))
    }))
    writer.write(example.SerializeToString())
writer.close()

#Open tfrecords using dataset api and batch data
filenames = ["test.tfrecords"]
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames)
def _parse_function(example_proto):
    keys_to_features = {'num_value':tf.VarLenFeature(tf.int64),
                        'list_value':tf.VarLenFeature(tf.int64)}
    parsed_features = tf.parse_single_example(example_proto, keys_to_features)
    return tf.sparse.to_dense(parsed_features['num_value']), \
           tf.sparse.to_dense(parsed_features['list_value'])
# Parse the record into tensors.
dataset = dataset.map(_parse_function)
# Shuffle the dataset
dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=1)
# Repeat the input indefinitly
dataset = dataset.repeat()  
# Generate batches
dataset = dataset.padded_batch(3, padded_shapes=([None],[None]), padding_values=(tf.constant(-1, dtype=tf.int64)
                                                 ,tf.constant(-1, dtype=tf.int64)))
iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
i, data = iterator.get_next()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run([i, data]))
    print(sess.run([i, data]))
```

What I have tried so far is to use a boolean mask, described here [Filter out non-zero values in a tensor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42194051/filter-out-non-zero-values-in-a-tensor)

However, my attempt just flattens all the tensors in the batch. Here is the code I used

```
filenames = ["test.tfrecords"]
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames)
def _parse_function(example_proto):
    keys_to_features = {'num_value':tf.VarLenFeature(tf.int64),
                        'list_value':tf.VarLenFeature(tf.int64)}
    parsed_features = tf.parse_single_example(example_proto, keys_to_features)
    return tf.sparse.to_dense(parsed_features['num_value']), \
           tf.sparse.to_dense(parsed_features['list_value'])
# Parse the record into tensors.
dataset = dataset.map(_parse_function)
# Shuffle the dataset
dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=1)
# Repeat the input indefinitly
dataset = dataset.repeat()  
# Generate batches
dataset = dataset.padded_batch(3, padded_shapes=([None],[None]), padding_values=(tf.constant(-1, dtype=tf.int64)
                                                 ,tf.constant(-1, dtype=tf.int64)))
# Create a one-shot iterator
iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
i, data = iterator.get_next()

neg1 = tf.constant(-1, dtype=tf.int64)
where1 = tf.not_equal(data, neg1)

result=tf.boolean_mask( data , where1)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run([data, result ]))
```

And this is the result

```
[array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3, -1],
       [ 2,  3,  4, -1, -1],
       [ 3,  6,  5,  4,  3]]), array([0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 6, 5, 4, 3])]
```

I need sometime that preserved the shape of the tensors. So the result would be something like

```
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
           [ 2,  3,  4],
           [ 3,  6,  5,  4,  3]])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ragged tensors. Altering code from above.

```
iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
i, data = iterator.get_next()

#Remove padding
data2= tf.RaggedTensor.from_tensor(data, padding=-1)
```